# Will home router retain dynamic IP?

Tags: networking, router, ip, isp, dynamic-ip

The cable from my ISP is connected directly to my computer. Problem is I have a dynamic IP address that changes every time I disconnect and reconnect, otherwise it will not change by itself if I stay connected. I was wonder how can I circumvent the issue,  if I buy a home router, will it retain the IP address in case I restart or disconnect?

Comment: In the LAN, you can have static IPs for your devices. Even if you buy a router, it will have a static IP in the LAN, but in Internet, you will have a dynamic IP address unless you buy one( or get one) from the ISP.

Answer (score 2):

No. your global Ip will keep on changing until you will ask/buy a static ip for your connection.

Dont know about your area, but that is very easily possible by paying very nominal amount.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to have a no-ip account. If you rely on having the same ip address or hostname you can usually set up an account with no-ip for free http://www.noip.com/

Answer (score 0):

From your ISP's point of view the router is now the connected device. It will seem always on and the IP address assignment will behave as if you left you pc on all the time in your current setup.

If this will give you a stable IP address I cannot say. That depends on other configuration options at the ISP's end. I have seen ISPs that give you a stable address for months as long as you don't disconnect. I have also seen ISPs that change the address every day even if you stay connected.

As others have already suggested: if this is really important to you you should pay the ISP for a fixed address. If you just want your address to be a little bit more stable then a router will probably help.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I hoped. Wanted to make sure before I buy a router. I've been connected for 2 days and it haven't changed yet. I do have a no-ip account, but I prefer to work with a router if it'll retain an IP.

Comment: It will retain it at least for a little bit. No guarantees though. You'll have to buy those from your ISP ☺